# How to properly disable smooth scrolling in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

If I disable smooth scrolling in chrome, then my mousewheel scroll works extremely fast. However, when I use my mouse left-click on the vertical bar to scroll, this is still as slow as it was before. How to apply smooth scrolling to all types off scrolling, not just mousewheel scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

Mouse scrolling speed is dependent on the settings for the Mouse. 
There are speed settings for the mouse in Control Panel, Mouse.

These settings are not for each application, so you cannot set up your Mouse just for Chrome.

I use my Mouse Wheel carefully so scrolling works on whatever app I am using, including Chrome.

You can change smooth scrolling within an app (e.g. Chrome) and that may help

Comment: My mouse scrolling speed inside Chrome was previously slow only because of the Chrome "smooth scrolling" settings. Once I disabled that, my mouse scrolling was fast, and I didn't change any Mouse settings. My problem is the click & drag scrolling, where I left click on the vertical scrolling bar and drag it - this is still very slow (maybe 500ms of latency).

Comment: So smooth scrolling was a Chrome issue.

Comment: Yes and I have fixed it a while ago for my mouse wheel. But the other method of scrolling remains slow (using my left mouse click, instead of using my mouse wheel).

Comment: So I have answered your question for you

Comment: I had already fixed the specific issue you discussed (mousewheel lag) before I made my OP. I said this in the first sentence of my post, "If I disable smooth scrolling in chrome, then my mousewheel scroll works extremely fast." The question I asked 
 ("How to apply smooth scrolling to all types off scrolling, not just mousewheel scrolling?") remains unsolved.

Comment: The mouse scrolling is independent of applications. The mouse looks after its own scrolling. Applications may have a scrolling feature built in but that is the app's responsibility